# How can I replace each new line with a auto-incremented number?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I am lookind for a effective way that I can replace newlines with an auto-incrementing number.

eg.

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

to

```
1. this is line 1
2. this is line 2
3. this is line 3
4. this is line 4
```

Is looping through each line the only way? I guess thats the way I will implement it for now. Unless I find a better way here :) Just some pseudo code will do. But I am using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
string[] lines = ...

string newText = string.Concat(lines.Select(
                     (line, index) => string.Format("{0}. {1}", index, line)));
```

Comment: `string.Format("{0}. {1}", index + 1, line)` with +1, the numbering will start from 1 rather than 0 is something I might use. I find the @org.life.java more intuitive still. but still thanks for an alternative C# answer

Answer (score 4):

This is probably easier if you use a shell command, for example:

```
nl -ba -s'. ' -w1
```

Comment: @codaddict Blank lines will not be numbered without `-ba`.

Answer (score 1):

> Just some pseudo code will do.

```
int lineNo=1;
for(String str:listOfString){
System.out.println(lineNo + " : " +  str);
lineNo++;
}
```

Note: code provided is written in java , You can get the basic idea from that